Can P-recursive functions assume only prime values?
A function $f\colon \{0,1,\dots\}\to \mathbb{R}$ is P-recursive if
it satisfies a recurrence $$
P_d(n)f(n+d)+P_{d-1}(n)f(n+d-1)+\cdots+P_0(n)f(n)=0,\ n\geq 0, $$
where each $P_i(n)\in \mathbb{R}[n]$ and $P_d(n)\neq 0$. Suppose that
$f$ is an unbounded integer-valued P-recursive function. Is $f(n)$
composite for infinitely many $n$? Surely this must be true, since
otherwise there is a simple recurrence that generates arbitarily large
primes.
What about more general recurrences? For instance, let
$F(x)=\sum f(n)x^n\in\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, where $f(n)$ is
unbounded. Suppose there is nonzero polynomial
$P(x_1,x_2,...,x_{k+2})$ such that $P(x,F,F',F'',\dots,F^{(k)})=0$. Is
$f(n)$ composite for infinitely many $n$?

I suspect that in general the recurrence will be periodic modulo all primes and it might be zero for infinitely many primes like the Fibonacci sequence.

@joro, certainly for each prime $p$ there is a cutoff $N_p$ and a period $d_p \le p^{d+2}$ for which $\forall n > N_p: f(n + d_p) \equiv f(n) \pmod{p}$. Proof: the tuples $(n \bmod p, f(n) \bmod p, \ldots, f(n+d) \bmod p)$ are the states of a deterministic finite state machine. The subtlety with trying to extend this into a proof that P-recursive functions must be composite for infinitely many $n$ is that walks in the FSM might be $\rho$-shaped rather than cycles.
